# Супервизор не может запустить Gunicorn: ENOENT, проблемы со статическими файлами

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisor

Пожалуйста, помогите мне. Возникли проблемы с развертыванием проекта django (версия 4.2.1) с использованием gunicorn, nginx, supervisor.

Структура каталогов проекта такова: [/root/workout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSDgr.png), [/myworkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLM4.png).

```
/root/workout
    /config
        gunicorn.conf.py
        workout.conf
    /static
        ...
    /media
        ...
    /venv
        ...
    /myworkout
        wsgi.py
        ...
    ...
```

Файлы конфигурации для gunicorn и supervisor: [gunicorn.conf.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvq0l.png), [workout.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL1UW.png)

`/root/workout/config/gunicorn.conf.py:`

```
bind = '172.18.0.1:8000'
workers = 2
user = 'root'
timeout = 120
```

`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/workout.conf:`

```
[program:workout]
command=/root/workout/venv/bin/gunicorn myworkout.wsgi:application -c 
/root/workout/config/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/root/workout
user=root
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /root/workout/logs/debug.log
startsecs=0
```

Supervisor выдает ошибку:

```
- supervisor: could not exec /root/workout/venv/bin/gunicorn: ENOENT
- supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

Однако, команда `gunicorn myworkout.wsgi -b 172.18.0.1:8000` позволяет загрузить сайт, но статические файлы не загружаются: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJEqI.png)

```
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
- Refused to apply style from 
  'https://myworkout.whitebeef.ru/static/workout/css/styles.css' because 
  its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, 
  and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

В свою очередь, файл конфигурации для nginx `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:` [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHgiq.png). Панель администрирования не закрывается...

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myworkout.whitebeef.ru;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    location /admin/ {
        allow 192.168.71.20;
        deny all;

        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.1:8000; 
            proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }    

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/root/workout/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        alias /home/root/workout/media/;
        expires 30d;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.1:8000; 
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Я пыталась решить проблему с разных сторон, проверила все пути, написала строку `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` в файле конфигурации nginx.

Comment: Теперь для начала логичный вопрос — что вы предприняли для того, чтобы этот самый `/root/workout/venv/bin/gunicorn` вообще существовал? Если вы говорите, что команда `gunicorn myworkout.wsgi` работает — где как вы её запускаете?

Comment: Было создано виртуальное окружение `venv`; gunicorn был установлен командой `pip install gunicorn`; `gunicorn myworkout.wsgi` работает только при запуске из каталога  `/root/workout`

Comment: А что насчёт активации виртуального окружения перед установкой и запуском gunicorn?

Comment: Да, было активировано